# Apply the css for different browsers

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to the web development.

Here I have a css which is ,

```
height: calc(100vh - 46px);
```

This works for all the browsers ,
But for the `mozila`,

```
height: -moz-calc(100vh -46px );
```

This works. So, How do I add the same for the diff browsers? As , I did this it is overriding the second one.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `calc` function works fine in "mozila" (assuming Firefox here) without the vendor prefix. A common practice is to add the rule without the prefix after the prefixed rules. This way if the standard rule is supported, it overrides all the possible older implementations of the CSS property.

Comment: Hmm ... Firefox has supported `calc` function since version 16, and the prefixed version doesn't even work in the current version of FF. Maybe it's the time to update your browser ..?

Answer (score 0):

`calc` is well-supported in Mozilla as far as I know. You can check [Can I use](https://www.caniuse.com/) for more information on what properties are supported on each browser.

Apart from that, you should do something like the following, adding prefixed rules after normal ones:

```
.my-style {
  height: calc(100vh - 46px);
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 46px);
}
```

The way browsers process CSS, only one will be applied, so there's nothing wrong with that.

If you want to skip the hassle of prefixing rules, you can use a tool like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to handle it all for you. [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) is also another option to see which rules need prefixing and how to do that properly.